# Retaining Contents in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my app i have created tabs using actionbar. In each tab there is a gridview of image. There is a keyboard initially in the app which on click puts image into edittext. But when i click on a tab and select an image passing it to edittext the previous contents are lost. How do i retain the previous content and append the image selected from grid in tab to already existing contents in edittext.

**Mainactivity class extends FragmentActivity.**

Need this to be done urgently. Please give your suggestions as early as possible.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SpannableString to do that. I found this code somewhere, it should work but in case it doesn't at least you have an idea of what you need to do.

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(yourEditText.getText().toString());
Drawable d = img.getDrawable();
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
yourEditText.setText(ss);
```